# How to generate cshtml class file in console app with dotnet cli?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

Having a cshtml folder in net 6.0  Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" project,

using the vs for mac, i can add follow properties in csproj file

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="Templates\A.cshtml">
        <Generator>RazorTemplatePreprocessor</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>A.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </None>
      <None Update="Templates\B.cshtml">
        <Generator>RazorTemplatePreprocessor</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>B.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Templates\A.cs">
        <DependentUpon>A.cshtml</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
      <Compile Update="Templates\B.cs">
        <DependentUpon>B.cshtml</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
```

and the cs file will auto generated in Templates folder.

but when in linux env, there is no vs for mac, then how to compile cshtml file to cs file

and import the cs file template to code,  then generate html string send to email?

Answer (score 0):

after all, I  found an easier solution with [RazorTemplating](https://github.com/soundaranbu/RazorTemplating)

add this package

```
    <PackageReference Include="Razor.Templating.Core" Version="1.7.1" />
```

and

in code:

```cs
// assume the Templates is a folder in the project directory first depth
// and this usage code file is in Other first depth folder
var emailContent = await RazorTemplateEngine.RenderAsync("Templates/SupervisorDigest.cshtml", htmlModelRecord);
```

it just works, and simple than visual studio precompiletool